# Fourier Transform of $f(t+a)$ if $f(t)$ has tranform $F(k)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I know the formula $$f(t) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(k)e^{ikt} \, dk$$ and I've seen that for computing $f'(t)$ it's a case of differentiating $e^{ikt}$ inside the integral, so $f'(t)=ikF(k)$

Can someone explain how I'd quickly work out $f(t+a)$ given $f(t)=F(k)$?
What if it was $f(at)$?
I presume it's going to involve some kind of substitution in the integral but I'm unsure how to go about it in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(t) = f(t+a), h(t) = f(at)$, then:

$G(k) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)e^{-ikt} dt = e^{ika}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t+a)e^{-ik(t+a)} dt = e^{ika}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-ikt}dt = e^{ika}F(k)$

$H(k) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)e^{-ikt} dt = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(at)e^{-i(k/a)(at)} dt = \dfrac{1}{a}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-i(k/a)t} dt = \dfrac{1}{a}F\left(\dfrac{k}{a}\right)$

Comment: I'm probably missing something straightforward here, but I don't understand how in the second line, the last integral, you have $\frac{1}{a}$ outside the integral, I'm not sure what happened there?

Comment: I think I see now it has to do with changing the variables, but why is it OK to still use $t$ and not some newly defined variable?

Comment: And also, in the first one, suppose you change variables by $u=t+a$, sub that in, gets you to $f(u)e^{-iku}$ but where does the $e^{ika}$ come from that gets factored out?

Comment: In this answer fh93 uses the formula for the Fourier transform. The one that appears in the question and in my answer is the formula for the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @user142340 For the $1/a$ factor, notice that if you make the substitution $t\mapsto t/a$, then $dt\mapsto dt/a$. As for the $e^{ika}$ factor, notice that $e^{-ikt} = e^{-ik(t+a-a)} = e^{ika}e^{-ik(t+a)}$ (which I've written as above to accentuate the use of the substitution $t+a \mapsto t$).

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of $f(t+a) $ is $F(k) e^{ika} $

$$f(t) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(k)e^{ikt} \, dk$$
$$ f(t+a) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(k)e^{ik(t+a)} \, dk= \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(k)e^{ika}e^{ikt} \, dk$$

And the Fourier transform of $f(at) $ is $\frac{1}{a}F(\frac{k}{a})$
$$f(at) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(k)e^{ikat} \, dk= \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{a}F(\frac{h}{a})e^{iht} \, dh$$
with $h=ka$ so $dh=adk$

Comment: What is your reasoning for this?

Comment: @user142340 These amount to just changes of variables in your integrals. Nothing more, nothing less.